# ArrayList, how can I compare and etc within? (Java)

Tags: java

So currently, I have an ArrayList that looks something like:

```
[ [id, type, name, $], [id, type, name, $], [id, type, name, $], [id, type, name, $]....]
```

Now say if i want to compare index 0 with 1, or maybe I want to add another value after the comma:

[id, type, name, $, YOLO]

How would I go about doing this? thanks!

Edit: here something:

I am reading data from Excel:

```
    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        Cell id = row.getCell(0);
        Cell type = row.getCell(1);
        Cell name = row.getCell(2);
        Cell $ = row.getCell(3);

    List temp = new ArrayList();
    temp.add(id);
    temp.add(type);
    temp.add(name);
    temp.add($);
  sData.add(temp);

}
```

and then when you print sData, it shows exactly how I said earlier.

Comment: You are required to post relevant example code. It's quite unclear to see what you're trying.

Comment: code involves lots of other functions and etc, I just wanted to understand how to do this part. I am getting all the data from a file and storing them in the ArrayList. I can make them all objects or all strings, its the way I choose to save them.

Comment: What is `sData`? I guess we're supposed to _guess_ that it's another list?

Comment: yeah stands for show data. that is the only way I could get all of the values to stick with each other while adding it to an array. Not sure on how to do this. basically, I want to keep a data structure to add/remove/compare within a structure like ArrayList, or whatever. Just want to be pointed at the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ArrayList in Java is a dynamic structure to hold a collection of objects.

In your case I suspect that you have an Object with attributes id, type, name and $ and you store them in the ArrayList using .add(Object) method.

What you want is to add another attribute to your Object and use the same method to add that Object to your ArrayList.

The thing you say about comparing the index.... (i suppose you mean the id variable of each object). Well that is also easy (suppose you implement the apropriate methods in your object - lets say for the variable id you should have a method setId and getId ... etc):

```
if(arrayList.get(0).getId == .... ){
    //do something
}
```

UPDATE

```
public class MyExcelRowObject {

    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String $;

    public MyExcelRowObject(){
        super();
    }

    public MyExcelRowObject(String id, String type, String name, String $) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.$ = $;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String get$() {
        return $;
    }

    public void set$(String $) {
        this.$ = $;
    }

}
```

And this is the manipulation of the Object

```
    //this is your Object's holder
    ArrayList<MyExcelRowObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyExcelRowObject> ();

    //here you manipulate your rows and add them to your MyExcelRowObject objects
    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        MyExcelRowObject tmpObj = new MyExcelRowObject();
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        tmpObj.setId(row.getCell(0));
        tmpObj.setType(row.getCell(1));
        tmpObj.setName(row.getCell(2));
        tmpObj.set$(row.getCell(3));

        myList.add(tmpObj);
    }

    //here is how you manipulate your List objects
    if(myList.get(0).getId().equals(myList.get(1).getId())){
        //the  ids of first and second row are the same
    }
```

Comment: the id, type, name and etc.. are all Strings already. So it isn't a variable id, or should I have set it that way?

Comment: do you have some written code that you can show us so tha we could understand what to you already have and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: basically what you have is ArrayList objects inside a bigger ArrayList, look at my update how i would do that...

Comment: I see what you did there, except id isn't a attribute. I've never done something like in that scenario. You can see how I am retrieving the data from that for loop, in what way can I create a attribute class where I can specifically assign each cell into each attribute type and update them into a ArrayList?

Comment: do not compare using ==, if you dont know that the data type is primitive or equal objects are shared (which is not know from the provided source)... This comparison might really misbehave. For example integers created via autoboxing are multitons (-128 - 127), hence this comparison might work on low numbers, but not on higher ones. But are not multitonts when created using new operator (comparison will never work).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ArrayList of ArrayLists, you could do the following to add an element to the first list:

`listOfLists.get(0).add("YOLO");`

Comparing the two lists is another story...

You'd have to iterate over both lists and compare each item:

```
boolean listsAreEqual(List<Cell> listOne, List<Cell> listTwo)
{
    if (listOne.size() != listTwo()) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < listOne.size(); i++) {
        if (! listOne.get(i).equals(listTwo.get(i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This assumes that you've implemented `equals` for `Cell` (whatever that is - not important here).

Since it appears that each item in your *sub-lists* are of type `Cell`, you should define your list like this:

`List<Cell> someList = new ArrayList<Cell>();`

This ensures that each element will be the same type.

It will be enforced at compile time, which is nice.

Comment: Don't have an IDE open, but wouldn't this be like: [id], [type], etc.. instead of [id, type, etc.]?

Comment: This won't work. I am not comparing two different fields. Why would I want to compare a ID with a type?

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know I could do that. I see your edit now, and I am sorry if I can't explain it any better. I can keep trying I guess. I am getting information from a file, lets say Excel or CSV or whatever. I am storing the x rows with x columns into a ArrayList or any other data structure I want. Then I want to be able to compare within the list for common $, or type and etc. Would a database work better?

Comment: Ok, I've officially read the updated one. It seems pretty good! I am so glad you asked me to edit my code in, or else I wouldn't have understood what you were doing here. Just a small question if you know the steps. So suppose, I was to compare two lists like you are doing in that function. Now [id, type, etc., $] format always stays the same. Once I compare two arrays and see that they are equal, since they are the same id, type, and other fields.. the only thing that would be different is $. Can I loop it so it creates a new final list to make it so: [id, type, name, $, $]. I've learned alot

Comment: I would vote up, except I don't have 15 reps, I can pick it the best answer though. That's fine if you are busy. I was just hoping since you already had most of the concept done, you can do small edits to help me understand. But thanks once again, I will keep them as cell objects when doing any comparisons. :)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.  `So it creates a new final list to make it so: [id, type, name, $, $]` does not make sense to me.

Comment: List implements equals, and is equals to another list if they're the same size and if all the elements are equal. Your listsAreEqual method could be replace with `listOne.equals(listTwo)`

Comment: A lesson to both @user1452530 and I to  read the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)